# Replace image element with inline svg in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to create a React component that changes the an image element to an inline svg element. I want to do this so I can insert svg elements from files in order to handle the styling with css.

Also important is that I'm using the create-react-app repository for my project and would love to be able to do this without ejecting my project.

The variable `req` returns a valid svg element which I set `this.state.response` that I then try to update but well.. it doesn't work. Using the code below I get the following error:

```
 A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

Code:

```
class Svg extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        response: undefined
    };
    this.toSvg(this.props.src);
}

toSvg(img) {
    const imageUrl = img;
    let self = this;

    // Create new XML Http Request to get data
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', imageUrl, true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            if ((this.status >= 200) && (this.status < 400)) {
                // Success!
                // Returns the HTML object
                let req = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

                self.setState({
                    response : req
                });
            } else {
                // Error :(
            }
        }
    };

    request.send(null);
}

render() {
    if (this.state.response === undefined) {
        console.log('no response rendering standard img');
        return <img src={this.props.src} alt='icon' />;
    }
    else {
        console.log('now we update');
        return this.state.response;
    }
}
}
```

If anyone knows how to handle the svg element to replace the img element without errors that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using `react-svg`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use [svg-inline-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-inline-loader)

```sh
# add npm package
npm install svg-inline-loader --save-dev
```

```js
# configure webpack loader
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
}
```

```js
# using in react code
<InlineSVG src={require("file.svg")} />
```

EDIT:

Currently in the `create-react-app` the [url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader) is used.

So you can manually configure file size limit to retrive *data URL*:

```js
require("url-loader?limit=10000!./file.svg");
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I were using the create-react-app so would like to be able to use without ejecting my project :D I'll update my question

Comment: The latter method causes the following error in create-react-app: "Unexpected '!' in 'url-loader?limit=10000!./drawing.svg'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders"  import/no-webpack-loader-syntax

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible in create-react-app 2.0 with a special import syntax:

```
import logoUrl, { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
```

References:

- [create-react-app 2
  proposal](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3856#issuecomment-358651855)
- [original feature request](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1388#issuecomment-440421025)